# How to ensure Chef nodes and EC2 instances are in sync?

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra

So, using knife we can create an EC2 instance and get its corresponding Chef node to show up on the Chef server, all with a single command. So far so good!

But do you have a tool or workflow for validating the link between instance and node? I had manually deleted an EC2 instance and so ended up with an orphaned Chef node.. it seems to me if I had a complicated network of instances I could've missed that. Or do you entirely bypass this by having a hard rule that no-one ever messes with EC2 instances directly, or something similar?

I'm new to Chef if it's not obvious, curious to understand how using Chef scales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chef records when a node last checked in under `node['ohai_time']` so you can use that to filter down results when using Chef for service discovery. A better option is to not use Chef for service discovery in favor of a tool built for it like ZooKeeper or Consul. Other than that, having orphaned data isn't really a huge deal so I generally ignore it. In the past I've also hooked up ASG scaling events to remove the associated node and client. I've also seen people put a script on the machine to be run on shutdown that removes its own node and client, though this can still leave orphans every now and then.